# Compare phone numbers from two tables with (-) symbol

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

This is my query for selecting table from MAJ that exist in the table user. However, both tables have two different format numbers to compare.

Phone number which is notel in user have (-) symbol , eg:019-9910922 and phone number in MAJ doesn't have that symbol, eg:0199910922.

Is there any other ways or solution where I can compare phone numbers(notel) in correct way?

```
SELECT * FROM MAJ WHERE EXISTS ( select * from user B WHERE A.notel = B.notel) AND SUBSTR('notel', 7,5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `REPLACE` mysql function to remove the - during comparison

I am unable to understand which of your tables (A or B) is the one with the -, but let's say it's B then your query becomes something like

```sql
SELECT * FROM MAJ WHERE EXISTS ( select * from user B WHERE A.notel = REPLACE(B.notel, "-", "")) AND SUBSTR('notel', 7,5);
```

The focus part is

```sql
REPLACE(B.notel, "-", "")
```

You simply take the original value (which contains -) and replace - with nothing.

This way you can compare the numbers.

Comment: thank youuu sir! It solved thanks to you. btw I ran your query but it turns error then I fix it by remove 'select ' near the 'replace' syntax .